# Make Entity Framework ignore Discriminator column

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, orm

I have a simple app with zero inheritance (at least as far as the database is concerned). How can I "tell" this to Entity Framework so that it would stop looking for the Discriminator column?

I don't have access to change the structure of the database tables, but I need to change the data, and I can't do it because EF keeps trying to operate on the non-existent `Discriminator` column and crashing as a result.

**Edit: Added code**

```c#
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
    }
}


public class UserRepository {
    public int Insert(User entity) {
        using (var db = new DatabaseContext()) {
            var table = db.Users;
            table.Add(entity);
            return db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class User : IEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Username { get; set; }

    public String Password { get; set; }

    public String FullName { get; set; }

    public String Email { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity {
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you change data?

Answer (score 0):

EF will only look for the Discriminator column if you use Table per Hierarchy inheritance on your DbContext.An example of a TPH DbContext class is this:

```
public abstract class Animal 
{
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public string Race { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string BarkStyle { get; set; }
}

public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Animal> Animal { get; set; }
}
```

You have to give up that pattern.

Comment: I am not using that pattern, please see the code I added. The only "inheritance" I can see is the IEntity implementation, but is that really the cause?

Comment: Well, it's not even inheritance what you're using, you are just implementing an Interface on the model class. I've never had the need to do that and I don't really know EF internals on hierarchy. What happens if you remove the interface from the class declaration and run the code?

Comment: Are you using MySQL Connector? I've had problems with MySQL Connector and discriminator columns before.

Comment: No, I'm using Npgsql and connecting to a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Try to use the regular SQL Server provider and see if the error raises, if it does not it might be a bug on the provider.